# Custom Field to a Role?

Tags: custom-field, user-roles

Is it possible to add custom field to a custom role? Say I want to create roles that represent a membership level and want to add billing options to it. So it'd look like this:

```
Membership level (Custom Role) | Billing options
-----------------------------------------------------------
Free                           | Null
Basic                          | Monthly, Quarterly, Yearly
Pro                            | Yearly, Bi-yearly
```

The thing I want to achieve is to create a membership level (role) and then on top of attaching capabilities to it, I want to store additional custom data on top of which I can build some business logic.
So a role object would look like this:

```
Role
|- Capabilities (array)
|- Custom Fields (array)
   |- Billing (single string)
   |- Upgrade options (single string)
```

Is this possible in Wordpress? Or I'm looking the wrong direction and this should be done in a different way?

Thanks in advance